# Feature no copyable code blocks

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

No copyable code blocks should be good feature, because it forces the questioner to write for yourself, and therefore promotes learning.

Comment: It also promotes typos ...

Comment: What exactly _is_ a "no copyable code block"? Once it appears on a web page, you can rest assured that it _can_ be copied.

Comment: Someone asks a question to receive an answer. We shouldn't make it harder for someone to use that answer.

Comment: Many modern browsers have developer tools; it isn't practical to prevent copying, and OCR is quite reasonable now. It doesn't matter if it's an image or text, anybody sufficiently skilled and willing will find a way to copy it.

Comment: I find all the downvotes on this quite unfair. It's a legitimate question, if not a good idea. This kind of thing scare users off of SO.

Comment: @Sean I agree, but unfortunately votes works different on meta.

Answer (score 21):

Apart from being completely impractical (if it is on the page, it can be copied - even if it is an image - that code can be retyped), the reasoning given doesn't make sense.

I don't see how preventing copying will promote learning.

Comment: _I don't see how preventing copying will promote learning:_ Everybody will learn that with this feature SO sucks...

Comment: I think the op's premise is built upon the act of rewriting something should help clarify understanding. But that is out of scope of what StackOverflow's purpose is

Comment: Making people type the code for themselves forces them to learn debugging skills when they make the inevitable typo. ;)